# writing string to a new row

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have code which writes the users name + surname + score in a excel file. But I want it to have header, so for example "Name" "Surname" and "Score" in the first row. Then every time the code is restarted I want the new data to store in a new column under those heading.

Comment: Please repost your code with some indentation. Given the importance of indentation in Python we would only be guessing what your code is meant to do as it stands.

Comment: @kdopen sorry , i did not know how to post it in exact way so i thought u just have to make everything in line with the text. Fixed the indentation now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to detect if the file you've opened has already had one or more lines written to it previously. An easy way to do this is to call the `tell` method on the file after you've opened it in append mode. `tell` will report the current position in the file, which will be the end in append mode. You only need to write the header if the position is `0`, since that indicates the file was empty.

```
if form == 'a': #if form entered is a 
    with open ('classa.csv','a',newline='') as keerthan:
        foo = csv.writer(keerthan,delimiter=',',)

        if keerthan.tell() == 0:                        # add this test!
            bar = ['Name', 'Surname', 'Score']
            foo.writerow(bar)

        bar = [[user,surname, score]]
        foo.writerows(bar)
```

Another thing (unrelated to the file header issue): you should really avoid duplicating so much code between different `if` statements. Often you can reuse the same logic, just with different values. Here's how you could turn the `if` above into a generic bit of code that can be used for all three forms:

```
filename = "class{}".format(form)       # use string formatting to get the right filename
with open (filename,'a',newline='') as keerthan:    # open the file using a variable name
    foo = csv.writer(keerthan,delimiter=',',)

    if keerthan.tell() == 0:
        bar = ['Name', 'Surname', 'Score']
        foo.writerow(bar)

    bar = [[user,surname, score]]
    foo.writerows(bar)
```

You can probably do something similar for your Q&A code, with the answer and the arithmatic operator being stored in variables.

Comment: thank you for your reply.Now i understand how to clean up my work ^^. Thank you for that help but for the heading part , i entered what you have suggested but got an error.  line 83, in <module>
    if keerthan.tell() == 0:                        # add this test!
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.                                 P.s - When the code is runned , it will create a file called class a for the first time so there will be nothing there , second time it is run the first data would be there.

Comment: I checked the excel file and the title seemed to be there but due to me having that error , I dont think my data is stored for example the name + surname + score below the heading accordingly.

Comment: Hmm, that error suggests that the file `keerthan` has been closed before you're calling `tell` on it. Are you sure that you have the indentation of the code right on your end? The `tell()` call needs to be indented as part of the block following the `with open(...) as keerthan` line. A `with` statement closes the file automatically when its block ends.

Comment: Yep , i tried indenting it other way aswell , indenting everything etc but still same error.

Comment: Hey , thanks it works now. Thank you for the help. I have one more question , Isit possible to make the heading bold and also make the column wider?. I know this is possible with xlsxwriter but I'm not allowed to use external packages in this project. Isit possible to do it with csv or something ?. Thanks :)